# Current Changes in the Primary Winding of a Transformer

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I'm an undergrad with an electronics repair background trying to find an explanation for one of the fundamental aspects of a transformer. Every explanation I've found of a transformer's basic operation insists that there is essentially no power loss; that is that VxI in the primary = VxI in the secondary. This suggests to me that if there was effectively no current in the secondary (i.e. it was an open circuit or there WAS no secondary) that current would more or less stop in the primary as well.

My instructor *adamantly* insists that this is not the case, and that current in the primary is constant no matter what might be happening in the secondary which *boggles* my dang mind as it seems to fly in the face of every explanation I see, and I have not been able to get a clear explanation out of him. If this were the case, then a device with a transformer would consume equal power regardless of whether it was operating or not! Right?

It seems to me from an intuitive and practical perspective that the EMF on the secondary should be relatively constant with respect to the voltage across the primary, and that the currents through each should be proportional at any given time, so that a changing load across the secondary should *somehow* influence the current in the primary, but I can't work out or find an explanation of that... mechanism. I feel like it must have to do with the secondary influencing the magnetic field in the core...

Please help! I've been wondering about this for years!

Answer (score 2):

For an ideal transformer if the secondary coil is open circuit then no current flows in the secondary coil but a current which is $90^\circ$ out of phase with the applied voltage flows in the primary.
Since the primary current and voltage are $90^\circ$ out of phase, in average over a period there is no net power transfer and as there is no current in the secondary there is no power output from the transformer.

It there is a resistive load $R$ across the secondary then the primary current and voltage are in phase with one another and the transformer and resistor behave as though there was no transformer and just a resistor of value $R/n^2$, where $n$ is the turns ratio of the transformer, across the primary voltage supply.

Answer (score 2):

Your instructor is wrong if he/she really said that: unless the primary is driven by a *current source* the primary current does depend on what happens in the secondary. Since the primary circuit is essentially an *inductor* that cannot be connected in series with a current source there is no "unless". We do not even have to assume that the transformer is an ideal one to see this, just note that the current through an inductor is determined by the (integral) voltage on its terminals be that from a voltage source or from a coupled inductor inducing that voltage through a mutually varying flux. The flux in the secondary coil is affected by its load and that load through the coupled flux *together* with the voltage source on the primary determine the current in the inductors.